# jquery `on change` doesn't recognize when you set textbox value programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to clear out a textbox when I call:

```
$('#textBox').val(''); or $('#textBox').empty();
```

Originally, when I would manually backspace and delete the text out of the text box, the `on change` function would fire. If I run `$('#textBox').val('')` above, `on change` does not fire:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#textBox').on('change', function(){
```

Why is this?

Comment: your `change event` will not fire if you `clear textbox` using jquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use trigger, like this:

```
$("#testBox").val("").trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 1):

When you change the value programmatically, just trigger the change event using [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

```
$("#myid").trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not jQuery that doesn't fire the event, it's the browser. If you look it up in the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents) you'll see the definition of the change event:

> change
>
> ```
> The change event occurs when a control loses the input focus and its value has been
> modified since gaining focus. This event is valid for INPUT, SELECT, and
> TEXTAREA. element.
>
>     Bubbles: Yes
>     Cancelable: No
>     Context Info: None
> ```

As already posted, your problem can be mitigated by triggering the event manually via [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).